# What are the plural forms of the words "octopus" and "platypus"?

Tags: grammatical-number, latin, greek

I've seen "octopuses" and "platypuses", respectively, but I've also seen "octopi" and"platypi". Which is correct, and why?

Answer (score 2):

*Octopuses* and *platypuses* would be correct. *Octopi* and *platypi* masquerade as Latin plurals on the false premise that the names are masculine Latin nouns of the second declension, and they are no such thing. The *-us* at the end is not analogous to the *-us* in *fungus;* rather it is part of the suffix *-pus* which is a Latinization of Greek ποῦς, *foot.* If you want to pluralize it in the true manner of its classical root, you would have to go with *-podes.* And that would be, frankly, a ridiculous extreme of pedantry.

Comment: _Octopi_ is listed in various English dictionaries as a valid alternative. I wouldn't choose it myself, but this is perilously close to the etymological fallacy. (_Platypi_ is also given by RHK Webster's.)

Comment: On the other hand, the [Latin word](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/polypus) for *octopus* is *polypus*, and the plural is *polypi*. It's not that wrong.

Comment: And then you will then have _octopodidae_ as the family which includes the octopuses. In French I see you can also form plurals from the singular [-pode](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-pode) to -podidés as in _octopodidés(fr)_ i.e. a familiy included in the _octopodes(fr)_ order which includes the octopus.

Comment: Ridiculous extreme of pedantry? Ouch! _Octopodes_ and _platypodes_ are hardly etymologically defendable (as comments in the question this one is marked as a duplicate of show), but it’s what I personally grew up saying, and it's the normal plural for me. I realise I’m in the minority here (and _octopuses/platypuses_ sound perfectly fine to me as well—they’re just not what I’d normally say myself), but I don't think I’m _that_ pedantic …

Answer (score -1):

Platypuses and octopuses are technically correct because both are not latin words although either is fine.  On the other hand, there are some English words that do have correct plurals that end with -i such as hippopotami (hippopotimus) and radii (radius).

Comment: What does 'technically correct' mean? It sounds like 'are formed according to traditionally more acceptable morphological rules'. But usage is what ultimately governs acceptability; recognition of false appeals to etymology for acceptability has actually encouraged the coining of the compound noun 'etymological fallacy'.